# Google OAuth 2.0 redirect_uri_mismatch error

Tags: url, redirect, http-headers, google-oauth, mismatch

1. I created a Google OAuth 2.0 `ClientID` and `secret` in Google Developer console
2. After that I tested in Google OAuth playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground).
   and registered `ClientID` and `secret` already created above and applied to Google OAuth 2.0 playground setting menu.
3. Some people say that after creating `ClientID`/`secret` they need some time for testing. So after two days I tried to test in the same conditions but the error is same `redirect_uri_mismatch`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: well, do they match?  character by character including protocol and trailing slashes? Sometimes the API console needs a kick, so try making a change (eg. add a second redirect URL)

Comment: Also check subdomain. I was missing a www.

Answer (score 6):

As little as having a '/' at the end of your uri and not having the same '/' at the end in your code will throw it off.

Answer (score 6):

Your `site URL` and the `Authorized redirect URIs` in developer console should be the exact match.

This kind of error occurs if one URL has `www` (`http://www.example.com`) and the other URL is `non-www` (`http://example.com`).

Other common URI mismatch are:

- Using `http://` in Authorized Redirect URIs and `https://` as actual URL, or vice-versa
- Using trailing slash (`http://example.com/`) in Authorized Redirect URIs and not using trailing slash (`http://example.com`) as actual URL, or vice-versa

Here is the step-by-step procedure (with screenshots) to update the **Authorized redirect URIs** in Google Developer Console (For those like me who found it difficult to get to that page).

> 1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com
> 2. Select your Project

[image: Select your Project]

> 3. Click on the menu icon

[image: Click on the menu icon]

> 4. Click on `API Manager` menu

[image: Select API Manager menu]

> 5. Click on `Credentials` menu. And under `OAuth 2.0 Client IDs`, you will find your client name. In my case, it is `Web Client 1`. Click on it and a popup will appear where you can edit **Authorized Javascript Origin** and **Authorized redirect URIs**.

[image: Select Credentials menu]

Here is a Google article on [creating project and client ID](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project).

Answer (score 3):

It should be a exact match what you have given in the console.developers.com.

In my case I missed the www in the url.

For eg: you have given http://www.google.com but in console.developers.com you gave http://google.com

It will still throw error. So it should be exact match.

Answer (score 2):

The redirect URI (where the OAuth response is returned to) has to be registered in [Google APIs console](https://cloud.google.com/console/), and the error is indicating that you haven't done that, or haven't done it correctly.

Go to the console for your project and look under API Access. You should see your client ID & secret there, along with a list of redirect URIs. If the URI you want isn't listed, click edit settings and add the URI to the list.

Comment: in new Google Cloud console, I don't see any Redirect URLs even one place to add them

Comment: APIs & auth >> Credentials.  Under OAuth, click Edit settings.  The second field is redirect URI.

Comment: @derpface there's no "Edit settings" on the latest console (Sep 2015)

Comment: @Dan the name of the OAuth 2.0 client IDs is a link.  Click on it and it takes you to the edit screen.  Makes you wonder if the UI people at Google ever heard of the principal of least surprise. (Sep 2015)

Comment: I am having the same issue and even when I click on the Client ID that just bring up a screen with the ClientID and SecretKey but no place to add redirect urls.

Comment: Go to `APIs & auth` > `Credentials` and then `Add credentials` > `OAuth 2.0 Client ID` and then specifically select `Web application` and then it should have spots for `Authorized redirect URIs`.  My old one was of type `other` and didn't have the `Authorized redirect URIs`.

Answer (score 2):

I kept getting this same error until I realized that I needed to put "signin-google" at the end of the redirect setting in the Google API console, like this (ie, NOT http://www.example.org/api):

```
http://www.example.org/api/signin-google
```

Answer (score 1):

(Magento 1.*) if You use inchoo Social Connect Magento extension then:

- Set below url in your google app (`OAuth 2.0` client IDs):
- 1. Authorized Redirect URIs: `http://www.example.com/socialconnect/google/connect/`
- 2. Authorized JavaScript Origins: `http://www.example.com`

Don’t forget to replace `http://www.example.com` with your domain

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that in your google-client-api, the value of credentials in these field are matched as what you got from [Google API console](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=devconsole&passive=1209600&continue=https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect&followup=https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect#project:248630263737):

```
$client->setClientId('xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('xxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://example.com/oauth2callback');
$client->setDeveloperKey('xx');
```

This could happen when the value of setRedirectUri is different from the one you set in Google API console.