# Google Calendar API python redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: python-2.7, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

[image]I'm trying to create a web application in python that uses Google Calendar API to access authenticated user's calendar. I created a test app which uses a *native app client id* and is able to successfully pull the info. However, when I try to do this for a **web application**, the redirect is not working. I keep getting the **redirect_uri_mismatch** error saying it is not registered, but I have already registered the uri in google api console.

I've read that others have had this problem with "localhost" as their uri, so I configured my hosts file/console redirect uri to have a "xyz.example.com" uri - but still no luck.

Hope someone can help with this, I've been struggling for hours trying to get it to work!

Thanks!

[EDIT] Attached a screenshot of redirect URI from Google API console. This is what it should redirect to, but for some reason it is not.

Comment: Share the snippet of your redirect_uri param. Are you trying to redirect Google OAuth services to your localhost?

Comment: If you go to your developers console, Under APIs and auth->credentials, are you seeing redirect_uri along with client_id and client_Secret? If URI is not there, edit settings and add URI. This should match with your redirect_uri. Also, for web applications, you need valid domain as redirect_uri. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224946/google-oauth-2-0-redirect-uri-mismatch-error

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to redirect google oauth services to localhost. Under APIs, credentials, there is a client_id/secret/redirect_uri that matches the redirect path on my service.