# ASP.Net - Google Calendar API V3 redirect_uri_mismatch error

Tags: asp.net, google-calendar-api

I am getting redirect_uri_mismatch error while getting refresh token using Google Calendar API V3. I have web application, which shows google calendar access consent window to user and if user allow access than i store refresh token received from request to my database. I also have windows service which runs once daily. This service fetch google calendar events for all users who have allowed calendar access into my application. It is working fine in my local environment but gives error on live site.

I have choose **Application Type** as **Other** while generating client id and secret. How can i resolved this error on live URL or where can i change redirect uri in Google API Console?

I have both web application and windows service using calendar api so i want same client id and secret needs to be used for both. Generating separate token for application type web application and other for windows service is not an option for me because i have tried that and it throws unauthorized client error while windows service try to fetch calendar events using refresh token generated throw web application client id & secret.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you are using the web redirect flow instead of the recommended flow with JS widget support. The web redirect flow does not take advantage of many features such as Cross-Device Sign-On, Over-the-Air Install, and so on.

This issue is related to the *Authorized Redirect URI* field settings for the Client ID.

To resolve:

- Access your list of credentials in the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apis/credentials) .
- From the project drop-down, select your [project](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158853) .
- On the Credentials page, look for the list of *OAuth 2.0 client IDs*, and select the web application client ID. This takes you to a details page.
- In the *Restrictions* section, the *Authorized Redirect URI* field(s) should contain the appropriate protocol, host name, port, and path information that will receive the redirected flow.

Here's a related SO ticket: [Google OAuth 2.0 redirect_uri_mismatch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224946/google-oauth-2-0-redirect-uri-mismatch-error)

Comment: redirect uri change option is only available if you have selected **Application Type** as **web application**. I am using type other because i want to use same credential in windows service also.