# HTTP 400 "redirect_uri_mismatch" error when trying to authenticate to Google Cloud with Postman

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, monitoring, postman, stackdriver

I'm using Postman to authenticate with Google Cloud but I'm receive a HTTP 400 Error redirect_uri_mismatch when I request the token. The values I'm using are below:

[image]

I was looking at [another reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34462452/7044148) on StackOverflow and was wondering if creating a web application client ID for Postman in my GCP project would resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the callback/redirection url on GCP correctly? It should be `https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback`